# Angular 2 - Pass variable to ng-template

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have this ng-template. Everything works with the loop. The only problem is that i can't pass the "title" variable with the "let-title".

What's wrong with my syntax? Do I need the asterisk to *ngIf?

"selectPerm(title)" doesn't work. It is always undefined.

```
<ng-template ngFor
             let-perm
             let-title="permission.title"
             [ngForOf]="permission.data.permissions"
             *ngIf="editForm.controls.permissions.controls[permission.data.id].value == '0'">
             <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{perm.name}}</td>
                <td><label>Allow: <input type="radio" value="1" formControlName="{{perm.id}}" (click)="selectPerm(title)"></label></td>
                <td><label>Deny: <input type="radio" value="-1" formControlName="{{perm.id}}" (click)="selectPerm(title)"></label></td>
                <td></td>
             </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I believe you are referencing the variable permission, but you have not declared that variable. permission.title will fail because permission is undefined. Not sure, but would replacing `permission.title` with  `perm.title` solve it?

Comment: 1. ngFor NgForOfContext create a context from ngForOf and let-title won't do anything. 2. if think u can apply only one strutual directive to an element. so no ngFor and ngIf together.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing your *ngIf on your "tr" tag and then referencing `perm.title` instead of a template input variable:

```
<ng-template ngFor
         let-perm
         [ngForOf]="permission.data.permissions">
         <tr *ngIf="editForm.controls.permissions.controls[permission.data.id].value == '0'">
            <td></td>
            <td>{{perm.name}}</td>
            <td><label>Allow: <input type="radio" value="1" formControlName="{{perm.id}}" (click)="selectPerm(perm.title)"></label></td>
            <td><label>Deny: <input type="radio" value="-1" formControlName="{{perm.id}}" (click)="selectPerm(perm.title)"></label></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
</ng-template>
```